# Is Yoda made using CGI in the original Star Wars or is it practical effects?

Tags: star-wars, effects

In the original Star Wars trilogy, was Yoda made using CGI available at that time or was he made using practical effects (like a puppet)?

Comment: Jim Henson and Frank Oz were involved. *One guess*... (Those two were the most famous puppeteers in the world at the time, responsible for *Sesame Street* and spinoffs, not to mention *The Dark Crystal*...)

Comment: All the original Star Wars trilogy (not counting the special editions) was practical effects.

Comment: Also no coincidence at all that Yoda was the same size as a Muppet.

Comment: CGI (as we know it today) was not available at the time - even the laser/blaster fire was not CGI - they were hand-painted on film

Comment: I'm genuinely curious. How young do you have to be to assume that CGI has always existed for as long as films have existed? This is like hearing my son working out whether events like WWII happened when I or Granny or Great-granny were alive, back when he was about 5 or so.

Comment: @Graham Random: my little sister found my GTA 1 CD, started playing it, then after a while asked me how to take it out of top-down view into 3D. Sweet summer child. And _that_ must have been 15 years ago.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Ironically, having said that, I was even more impressed when I saw the extended edition version of *Aliens*, not just for the extra (awesome) deleted scenes, but for the "making-of" documentary.  I had literally never thought about how they made the powerlifter and Alien queen work.  The fact that this was done using insane-level puppeteering with 12-foot-tall models *with Sigourney Weaver inside one*, especially with the deleted scene in the extended version with a long cut where they stalk around each other to look for an opening - that just blew my mind. :)

Comment: @Graham CGI existed by the time The Empire Strikes Back was released, even if it was primitive and not used in many films. I don't think it's that surprising for someone to think it's possible that Yoda was animated, if they didn't already know the history of CGI.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica: only one trilogy, there is! Harrumph!

Comment: Sorry, clearly not all effects were practical. Many were hand-painted or composited post-production effects.

Comment: @JustinLardinois Can you cite any examples?  Even Tron (1982) came out *five years* after A New Hope (1977), and two years after Empire (1980) - and that is generally the milestone that demarcates the introduction of CG to cinema.  The trench run briefing vector displays *were* CG in A New Hope, but that is a *far cry* from the sophistication necessary to create a fully kinematic, textured, lifelike character.

Comment: @J...: The DVD of "Man with a Golden Gun", in a period promotional featurette about one of the stunts in the movie, includes a 1973 computer animation of the stunt.

Comment: @supercat "a 1973 computer animation of a stunt" -- not a practical rendering of the stunt as part of a movie. I'm assuming more of a line tracing of movement or such...? Modern CGI simply wasn't feasible in 1973

Comment: There is a reason Yoda sounds *exactly* like Grover from Sesame Street!

Comment: @StephenR: It was presented as being a simulation performed by a "FORTRAN computer", but it took the form of a line-graphic animation rather than a bunch of numbers.  I mention it because it's the earliest example I know of where moving computer-generated imagery appears in a film intended for viewing by the general public (I know there were some tech demos before that, but few people would have seen them).

Comment: @J... you missed my point. A casual viewer isn't going to know which films first used certain effects or exactly when they came out. I was just saying that this isn't a ridiculous question.

Comment: @JustinLardinois I don't want to believe that I'm so old that the majority of people don't remember when we didn't have computers.

Comment: For anyone interested in James Bond CGI car from 1973: https://jalopnik.com/the-james-bond-corkscrew-jump-was-the-first-computer-mo-1711459704

Comment: @quetzalcoatl it's not CGI. Read your link. They modelled the jump with a computer to be sure it would work correctly when they filmed it.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica well I might used too few words for it, but if you look carefully at all the materials, you will find a wireframe rendering that presents the results of that simulation. That's totally a CGI, and I suppose you can say it's a CGI of a James Bond's car. That's what this simulation was all about, right?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl but you're presenting it as if the shot in the film was CGI

Comment: I’m pretty sure if you tried to render modern CGI on a computer in 1980, **it would still be rendering today**

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The Yoda in the 1980 *Empire Strikes Back* and in the 1983 *Return of the Jedi* was entirely realised using puppetry.

Here we see Frank Oz (the chief puppeteer and voice of Yoda for the two movies):

[image: Frank Oz and Yoda]

And here's a video of the behind the scenes footage:

CGI in 1980 and 1983 was in no way capable of rendering anything like Yoda. Here is arguably the best effort of CGI from 1984:

Even when CGI was used for Yoda in the prequels, we see the result is good but still not quite so realistic as the original puppets:

[image: Yoda in Attack of the Clones]

Comment: Frank Oz was in the credits wasn't he...? This should have been a 'no-brainer'.

Comment: @Jeeped Frank Oz is credited in the movies which use a CGI Yoda, so not sure how that's a no-brainer.

Comment: I'll have to review the credits from the earlier movies. I thought his puppeteer skills were front and center.

Comment: Totally quibbling, but that "behind the scenes" video doesn't contain footage, just stills.

Comment: While a bit disappointed in CGI Yoda myself, there is no way a Puppet Yoda vs Dooku or Palpatine would have been nearly as good.

Comment: Anyone who's familiar with the Muppets should've recognized Yoda.  Odd syntax aside, it's the same voice as Gonzo, also animated and voiced by Frank Oz.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Yes, but how about Puppet Yoda vs. Puppet Dooku?

Comment: I liked puppet Yoda way better.......CGI Yoda just looks like a cute puppy with creepy eyes

Comment: Not Gonzo’s voice so much as Grover’s

Answer (score 22):

The first real attempt to incorporate a CGI character in a movie was *Terminator II* (1991), more than a decade after the introduction of Yoda (1980).

(http://www.historyofinformation.com/detail.php?id=3561)

Computers in 1991 were so primitive, James Cameron invented the liquid metal T-1000 because it was the only kind of CGI effect that wouldn't look awful a few years later — it was supposed to look fake.

[image: The T-1000]

But 90s CGI is usually pretty bad. George Lucas began redoing the original trilogy's special effects when he rereleased *A New Hope* for its 20th anniversary. The version on the left is the original Jabba puppet; the version on the right is the best 1997 CGI could do:

[image: Jabba Comparison]

(https://imperialtalker.com/2016/06/07/jabba-the-cgi-hutt/)

My personal dividing line for when CGI characters got realistic enough to be invisible is *Rise of the Planet of the Apes* (2011):

[image: Rise of the Planet of the Apes]

Comment: Loved your insightful answer about how the technology has evolved in the 90s.

Comment: There's a good side-by-side comparison of the two Jabba the Hutt's here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Br0R5kMzwM

Comment: The first CGI character was even earlier - 1985's [Young Sherlock Holmes](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.syfy.com/syfywire/firsts-the-first-all-cgi-character-made-before-pixar-became-pixar%3famp)

Comment: *The Abyss* from 1989 had the water tentacle character that was CGI, and predates *Terminator 2*. As both were James Cameron movies, *The Abyss* probably laid the groundwork for the T-1000 to appear at all.

Comment: Every generation of video games and CGI looks totally real until you see the next one.

Comment: @ReinstateMonicaSackTheStaff. To be fair though, the differences between successive generations appear to be converging to an asymptote of zero. It really is getting to the point where it's impossible for a casual observer to tell.

Comment: I didn't know they CGI'd James Franco in that movie! ;)

Comment: You're all forgetting 1982's Tron also had a fully CGI character, [Bit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcyCWEsbsPU) (who was surprisingly expressive considering the simplicity of his model and the limitations of his vocabulary).

Comment: @jmbpiano: Fond as I am of *Tron*, Bit didn't have any face, anatomy (well not really), voice, emotions etc. Calling him a 'character' is stretching things... you might as well call CGI stars (the things in the sky, that is) characters.

Comment: I can recall right about the time the original Men in Black came out reading that CGI movies started with dinosaurs and other "slick" creatures because the hardware was not yet capable of rendering anything as complex as fur.  Notably, in that movie there's a CGI sequence where they shot off an alien's head (alien played by Tony Shaloub) and the head grows back, but the creature's hair in CGI shot is slicked down

Comment: Insightful as this might be, it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @smci Watch the clip I linked. Bit most certainly has voice, and demonstrates emotions and rudimentary personality. It's also an excellent example of the severe limitations of the tech contemporaneous with the release of Empire and Jedi.

Comment: @jmbpiano: No it doesn't. Two digitized voice samples of a monotone 'Yes' and 'No'. *"emotions and rudimentary personality"* is really stretching things, like I said. This ain't a character.

Answer (score 21):

**In the original trilogy** (i.c. *Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back*, and *Episode VI: Return of the Jedi*, since in *Episode IV: A New Hope* Yoda doesn't make an appearance), **Yoda was portrayed exclusively using puppets**:

> Frank Oz provided Yoda's voice in each film and used his skills as a puppeteer in the original trilogy and *Star Wars: Episode I – The Phantom Menace*. For some walking scenes in Episodes V and I, dwarf actors Deep Roy and Warwick Davis appeared in costume as Yoda [..]. While Frank Oz served as the primary performer, he was assisted by a multitude of other puppeteers [..].
>
> The make-up artist Stuart Freeborn [who designed the character and created the puppet] based Yoda's face partly on his own and partly on Albert Einstein's.

([Here](https://youtu.be/85MK2GDkoxo?t=1425)'s a really nice insight into the character design, and how it turned out to be somewhat of a self-portrait of Stuart Freeborn.)

It was actually **only after *The Phantom Menace* that Yoda became a complete CGI character**:

> In *The Phantom Menace*, he was redesigned to look younger. He was computer-generated for two distant shots, but remained mostly a puppet. The puppet was re-designed by Nick Dudman from Stuart Freeborn's original design.

In the 2011 re-release of Episode 1 on Blu-ray, Yoda ([among other things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxaZxpNTm8A)) was [recreated](https://www.highdefdigest.com/news/show/George_Lucas/20th_Century_Fox/Yoda_Goes_CGI_in_Star_Wars_Episode_I_-_The_Phantom_Menace_on_Blu-ray/7520) using CGI, however:

[image]

For the remaining two episodes of the 20th century sextology, his CGI appearance, however more dynamic, was still dictated partially by his puppet physics:

> His performance was deliberately designed to be consistent with the limitations of the puppet version.

<sup>[quotes from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda#Concept_and_creation)</sup>

Comment: So Greedo shoots puppet Yoda and replaces him with CGI Yoda?

Comment: @Machavity Yoda shot first!